# ¿Cómo hacer un Post FormData desde Blazor WebAssembly hacia un minimal Api en .Net Core 6?

Tags: .net-core, blazor

Actualmente me encuentro en el desarrollo de un sistema para practicar **Blazor webassembly** y a su vez utilizar **APIs desarrolladas como Minimal** desde otro proyecto. El hecho es que me encuentro con un obstáculo el cual he realizado re-search y no logro encontrar una solución y el mismo es **enviar archivos (en mi caso imagenes)** hacia la **minimal api**. La **Minimal API** como tal, **funciona** de forma excelente desde el Postman, pero no encuentro una manera para desde **Blazor enviar ese archivo** y sea recibido por mi **Minimal API de forma correcta**.

> En Blazor tengo el siguiente código:

```cs
<h1>Blazor Server File Upload</h1>

<InputFile OnChange="@UploadFile" />

@if (ImgUrl != null)
{
    <div>
        <img src="@ImgUrl" style="width:100px" />
    </div>
}

@code {
    private IWebHostBuilder _env;

    private string ImgUrl;

    private async Task UploadFile(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var pathToSave = Path.Combine(e.File.Name);
            await using FileStream fs = new(pathToSave, FileMode.Create);
            await e.File.OpenReadStream().CopyToAsync(fs);
            ImgUrl = Path.Combine(e.File.Name);
            //Http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")); ;
            //var response = await Http.PostAsJsonAsync("http://localhost:7220/uploadphoto/", fs.Name);
            var response = await Http.Post<SaveFile>("http://localhost:7220/uploadphoto2/", pathToSave);

            Snackbar.Add(response.ToString(), Severity.Error);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Snackbar.Add(ex.Message, Severity.Warning);
        }


    }

}
```

> Y el código de la Minimal API por si a alguien le sirve es el
> siguiente (**este código funciona correctamente**):

```cs
app.MapPost("/uploadphoto", async (DbContextMaster db, HttpResponse response, HttpRequest request) =>
{

    if (!request.Form.Files.Any())
    {
        await response.WriteAsJsonAsync(new { data = new { message = $"Status Code 500, Internal server error" }, File = "", Size = "", Fullpath = "" });
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {

            var folderName = Path.Combine("upload");
            var pathToSave = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), folderName);

            foreach (var file in request.Form.Files)
            {
                var fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');
                var fullPath = Path.Combine(pathToSave, fileName);

                using (var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    file.CopyTo(stream);
                    await response.WriteAsJsonAsync(new { data = new { message = $"File is uploaded Successfully" }, File = file.FileName, Size = file.Length, Fullpath = fullPath });

                    return;
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await response.WriteAsJsonAsync(new { data = new { message = $"Status Code 500, Internal server error" }, File = "", Size = "", Fullpath = "" });
            return;

        }

    }

})
    .WithName("UploadPhoto").WithTags("Uploads");
```

Si alguien ha podido solucionar el inconveniente, por favor que me dé luces para solventar este obstáculo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logre resolver el inconveniente comunidad, compartiré la solución al problema.

Primero que todo debemos saber que en el **Minimal API** debemos enviarle un cuerpo a **Form-data** para poder que la **imagen** sea almacenada en la ruta que queramos.

Teniendo esto claro necesitaremos lo siguiente, en el mismo orden de ideas, seguiremos los siguientes pasos:

- Vamos a instalar el Nuget de `tewr.blazor.filereader`
- En el `Program.cs` agregaremos el `using Tewr.Blazor.FileReader;`
- Agregaremos el servicio `builder.Services.AddFileReaderService();`
  en el `Program.cs`
- En el `_Imports.cs` agregaremos la línea `@using Tewr.Blazor.FileReader`

Ahora nuestro Blazor quedaría de la siguiente manera.

```
@using Tewr.Blazor.FileReader;
@inject IFileReaderService fileReader;

<input type="file" @ref="elementReference" @onchange="async () => OpenFileAsync()"/>
<MudText Typo="Typo.subtitle2">Nombre de archivo: @fileName</MudText>
<MudText Typo="Typo.subtitle2">Tamaño: @size</MudText>
<MudText Typo="Typo.subtitle2">Tipo: @type</MudText>

<MudButton OnClick="async () => UploadFileAsync()">Subir imagen</MudButton>

@code {

    ElementReference elementReference;
    string message = string.Empty;
    string imgPath = null;

    string fileName = string.Empty;
    string type = string.Empty;
    string size = string.Empty;

    Stream fileStream = null;

    async Task OpenFileAsync()
    {
        var file = (await fileReader.CreateReference(elementReference).EnumerateFilesAsync()).FirstOrDefault();

        if (file == null)
        {
            Snackbar.Add("Imagen no cargada", Severity.Error);
            return;
        }

        var fileInfo = await file.ReadFileInfoAsync();
        fileName = fileInfo.Name;
        size = $"{fileInfo.Size}";
        type = fileInfo.Type;

        using (var memoryStream = await file.CreateMemoryStreamAsync((int)fileInfo.Size))
        {
            fileStream = new MemoryStream(memoryStream.ToArray());
        }
    }

    async Task UploadFileAsync()
    {
        string url = "http://localhost:7220";

        var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data");

        content.Add(new StreamContent(fileStream, (int)fileStream.Length), "image", fileName);

        var response = await Http.PostAsync($"{url}/uploadphoto", content);

        message = "Imagen guardada con éxito";

        Snackbar.Add($"{message}", Severity.Success);
    }
}
```

Espero les sea de gran ayuda esta aportación. saludos **StackOverFlow Community**!